# convert svg with <textPath> to png

Tags: svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, rsvg

I am struggling to convert a svg to png. The file includes a `<textPath>` and is basically setup the same as this one [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath). I have installed imagemagick such that rsvg is/should be used for rendering of svg grafics.

```
$ convert -list delegate | grep -i svg
svg =>          "rsvg-convert" -o "%o" "%i"

$ convert -list format | grep -i svg
SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.18)

$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-03-15 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Converting the SVG linked above using `convert test-imagic.svg test-imagic.png` results in the following image:

[image]

which is not what I am after.

How can I get such an svg converted to png or any other pixel graphic format?

Comment: ImageMagick can use its internal MSVG/XML renderer or RSVG delegate or Inkscape. The internal one is not that good. RSVG is better and Inkscape is best. Try installing RSVG or Inkscape. You can see what you are using by `convert -list format` and check the line starting with SVG. It should tell you which is used. Inkscape may not show. But if you install Inkscape on your system then ImageMagick should use it. If you install RSVG, you may have reinstall ImageMagick so that RSVG is loaded as a delegate library.

Comment: INkscape as renderer is a neat idea, any link how to install it? Unfortunately I cannot change the setup on the host, so I have to stick to rsvg…

Comment: You have not said what your platform is? Linux, Mac, Windows? I only use a Mac and use MacPorts to install. Perhaps you should ask your hosting provider to install Inkscape. Your RSVG is a bit old. I am using 2.42.2. Perhaps you should post your SVG file.

Comment: Linux in production, for development its Ubuntu 17.10 within a docker container

Comment: Perhaps you should post a link to your SVG file

Comment: @fmw42 The svg is ok, works in the browser, inkscape, everywhere… It is the `<textPath>` that seams not to be implemented. Please note the versions of imagick i have posted, since these are the ones availble on the production server for me. Maybe it works for newer ones…